# ReferenceError: reload is not defined

Tags: javascript

Basically my first error was `TypeError: require(...) is not a function`, so I immediately put a ; at the end of `require("./handlers/slashcommands")`. But then I come home with this error: `ReferenceError: reload is not defined`. This is after I put ; after my requirment.
I'm mainly worrying about this part:

```
client.slashcommands = new Discord.Collection()

client.loadSlashCommands = (bot, reload) => require("./handlers/slashcommands");
(bot, reload)
client.loadSlashCommands(bot, false)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey Giga Chad, your code is not quite valid, what are you trying to achieve, what is the require supposed to give you back ?

I recommend you to do your requires in the begining of your file, and then use them

Comment: My goal is to use slash commands as my bot's prefix (in Discord), the requirement is declaring function "loadSlashCommands" so every time I run "node ./loadslash.js" it is supposed to load every slash command located in my slashcommands folder. Sadly it is giving the error and I do not know how to define "reload" since I always define bot by doing `bot, reload` or `bot, false` in my code. @kigiri

Answer (score 1):

`(bot, reload)`, by itself, is nonsense (and you get the error because `bot` and `reload` are arguments to the arrow function, so when you move `(bot, reload)` outside it, the variable isn't available).

It is supposed to call the function returned by `require(...)`.

Take the semi-colon back out:

```
(bot, reload) => require("./handlers/slashcommands")(bot, reload);
```

---

Then you need to address the real problem, which is that the `slashcommands` module is supposed to export a function, but currently doesn't.

Comment: Do you know how to make slashcommands a function? I am quite new to JS and HTML.

Comment: `module.exports = a_value_that_is_a_function`

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. All it gave me was ", expected."; Know anything else I can do? I'll give you the code again: `let bot = {`
    `client`
`}`



`const guildId = "997532386705277018"`

`client.slashcommands = new Discord.Collection()`

`client.loadSlashCommands = (bot, reload) => require("./handlers/slashcommands")(bot, reload);`
`client.loadSlashCommands(bot, false)`

`client.on("ready", async () => {`
   `const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)`
   `if (!guild)`
        `return console.error("Target guild not found")`

Comment: It should have told you **where** (file name, line number, line position) it expected a comma.

Comment: Nope, Even without putting a comma it still gives the error. Is my code outdated?